# optimal activerecord query format for number of X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, optimization, query-optimization

If for example a `Tweet` `has_many :favorites`, is it faster to call `Tweet.favorites.size` or to have a separate attribute/column in the database for a `Tweet` such as `num_of_favs`. While my initial thought was that `Tweet.favorites.size` was faster, I know that certain Rails optimization techniques detail creating your own counter_cache methods such as the `Tweet` model having a `favorites_size` attribute which isn't much different from `num_of_favs`. I am using `Postgres` btw.

Comment: Definitely faster to have a counter cache, because without one you're doing an additional query.

Comment: I've never considered the development time tradeoff to be worth it. But it just depends on how important it is to squeeze out every millisecond of speed to you.

Comment: @pixelearth so then would you say it's dependent on the database size of the records you're pulling from? For example if my site only has 50 tweets it wouldn't really matter but if it was 1000 it could make a big difference?

Comment: Wrote up a whole answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following console tests on some of my dbs. One has nearly 60,000 rows. Granted, this is not enormous by any means.

My tests show that counting the rows of this table are 30 times slower than retrieving a value from a row. But when you're talking about .4ms or 12ms, for me personally this is not worth the optimization for my projects. The last one is on an association. You can see the times followed by ms.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.1)
Loading ~/.railsrc
2.0.0-p247 :001 > Log.count
   (12.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `logs`
58133
```

and

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Log.first.method
  Log Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `logs`.* FROM `logs` ORDER BY `logs`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
"GET"
2.0.0-p247 :003 >
```

and

```
1.8.7-p352 :005 > Pack.last.lessons.count
  Pack Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `packs`.* FROM `packs` ORDER BY packs.id DESC LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `lessons` INNER JOIN `lessons_packs` ON `lessons`.id = `lessons_packs`.lesson_id WHERE ((`lessons_packs`.pack_id = 460))
 => 103
```